# Change characters in string - Not Exactly C language

Tags: string, nxc

I need to change one character in string. In normal C, this is done simply by changing the offset:

```
char string[]="Somestring";
string[1] = 'a';   //"Samestring"
```

But in NXC such operation is not supported. So how do I change charecter on a string offset. NXC documentation about their strings has 3 lines, so I'm quite helpless now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
string foo = "Somestring";
foo[2] = 'a'; // results in "Samestring"
```

Comment: Well, it seems there was some other error in my code, because this is exactly what I have tried. But thank you for assuring me about using the strings.

Comment: @TomášZato I think is was the way you initialized the string variable